# How to authenticate user using Twitter mobile app

Tags: ios, authentication, redirect, twitter, oauth

I'm currently authenticating user with Twitter using oauth flow inside a webView from the iOS app. However, I would like to authenticate user redirecting him to the native Twitter app if it is installed on the device.
The thing is that Twitter's [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter#tab3) doesn't mention anything like that. Only the oauth flow I'm currently using.

So my question here is how to do that? I know some apps are doing that (e.g. Clubhouse), but have no idea how to do that since the official TwitterKit SDK is deprecated for a while now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to authenticate using the installed Twitter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337062/how-to-authenticate-using-the-installed-twitter-app)